# Executing a php script in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to run a quick php script when users leave my website, and also pass a variable from my javascript to php but i'm not quite sure how to include the php file and pass it a var. But it's not actually running the php script. any ideas?

(the javascript gets the username from an external activity function, and i know that works i tested the var on an alert and its there.)

My JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            var username = null;

            function GetUsername(usernameff)
            {
                username = usernameff;
            }

            window.onbeforeunload = function () 
            {

            if (username != null)
            {

            <?php include("scripts/RemoveUserOnDisconnect.php?username=username");?>
            }

            }


            </script>
```

My RemoveUserOnDisconnect.php File:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("mysql.mysql.com", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("my_db");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE username = '$username'");         
?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try an ajax request. Depending on your php script you will need `$.post` or `$.get`

jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var username = null;

    function GetUsername(usernameff){
        username = usernameff;
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if (username != null){
          $.post('scripts/RemoveUserOnDisconnect.php', {username: username}, function(){
            //successful ajax request
          }).error(function(){
            alert('error... ohh no!');
          });

        }
    }
 </script>
```

EDIT:

Your php script should reference the `$_POST` array if you use my code above.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    mysql_connect("mysql.mysql.com", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("my_db");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE username = '$username'");         
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples! I gave it a shot, and have exactly what you posted. No luck though, any ideas? I tried putting a alert("it worked"); in place of your it worked comment, and the alert isn't coming up. Should I put like a return in front of the query to get it to trigger that function or something? to see if it's being executed? Also, I don't know if this could be it, but I'm only allowing "execute" permissions on the scripts folder. But i'm assuming that probably isn't the issue since i have other scripts in the folder being accesed just find through a cron job

Comment: are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: ohh I didnt know that was jquery, i thought it was just regular javascript. I have <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> up higher in the script, I also tried src="scripts/jquery.js" in the script tab that contains this and it still doesnt work

Comment: @brybam Sorry, I thought I was clear this was jQuery. In the `head` section of you HTML document, put this code. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Also, make sure the path to your `php` script is correct and everything should work fine, assuming your `php` code works. Good luck!

Comment: hmm. I know the php code works, i'm using the same exact code in a php function i reference with flash so i know it's working. I also know it's getting a username varable, because if i take out the code you recommended and put alert(username); it shows up. I thought i'd mention i tried,  `$.post('scripts/RemoveUserOnDisconnect.php', {username: username}, function(res){
          alert("results: " + res);` and the alert isn't even coming up

Comment: @brybam I edited the code to include an error function for `$.post`. Please use this code and if the error alert box comes up, I would bet that the path to your `php` script is incorrect. The path to the `php` script is going to be from the directory of your `html` document, so keep that in mind. If the error box does not appear, there is a problem with the javascript and or jQuery.

Comment: Well, tested with the error code, and received no error. Like I said if i put `if (username != null){
         alert(username);
          })
  }` the alert comes up with the users username just fine. But i looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and all your code looks right. So...well i duno. guess ill keep fiddling. thanks for trying and i will speak up if it works!

Comment: @brybam Something is wrong with jQuery. Perhaps you have conflicting scripts. The jQuery library needs to be loaded before the javascript code above. To help find the error, create a new html page that include the jquery source in the head element then afterwards, has the code above. If this doesn't work, I can't help without seeing all the code you are running.

Comment: Well, for some reason, with your post code it doesnt work with the `!= null code` no idea why... but it works! thanks a lot! I'll have to figure out the null thing i guess, so i can save some unneeded request to my db. thanks again!

Comment: Well username is null until you call getusername. Are you calling that somewhere before the window is closed?

Comment: I actually just deleted the whole thing and rewrote it..and now its all working. i seriously don't even know why its working now but it's all good. thanks! really appreciate the help

Comment: You're welcome. Read up on jQuery, it's pretty sweet stuff. Take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax call to scripts/RemoveUserOnDisconnect.php?username=username.  You cannot include PHP with Javascript, Javascript executes on the browser, PHP executes on the server..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call to the PHP script. Your javascript code will just make a background request to the php script which will execute those MySQL statements. Google up AJAX. Recommended: Learn jQuery and use ajax using `$.get()` or `$.post()`