# Zend : create PHP namespace through JQuery executing error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Sample code :

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#changePwYes').click(function(){
        <?php 
            $this->session = new Zend_Session_Namespace(Zend_Registry::get('config')->session->nameSpace);
            $this->session->showBox = "0";
        ?>
    });

});
```

This php script should be executed only when button clicked but executing while loading itself.

What to do

Comment: Yes that will. Cause `php` runs way before your jquery gets executed.

Comment: For dynamic you need to use ajax..

Comment: PHP runs on your server. JavaScript runs on your client's web browser. You can't mix them like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a php script in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227132/executing-a-php-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case, when you want to make some changes on server side from client side without page redirection, we have **AJAX**.

Call a **Zend controller** action from your click event trough **AJAX** :

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#changePwYes').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
         url: "myApp/public/index.php/controller-name/create-name-space/format/html",
         type: "POST",
         data:{mydata : 'test'}
         success: function(html){   
            alert('Done');    
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){       
            alert('An error occurred);
         }
        });
    });
});
```

In your **controller**, create a new **action** :

```
public function createNameSpaceAction()
{       
    //Disable the layout rendering for the ajax request
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    //Set no renderer in this case
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);    

    //Retrieve dada if needed
    $myData = $_POST['mydata'];

    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace(Zend_Registry::get('config')->session->nameSpace);
    $session->showBox = "0";    
}
```