# Execut a php function with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, call

i need to make a page that have  a button , when i press that button , a javascript function call a php function who run a mysql_query and print on page the results! How can i run php function from javascript .

Comment: Use Ajax to achive this.

Comment: What did Google have to say?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a php script in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227132/executing-a-php-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

```
    $.ajax({
       url : 'script.php'
    });
```